# Rails route if no route matched

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is there a solution to redirect the user to a specific controller#action if no route matched? I had a "last rule" like this:

```
 match ":rest" => "application#notfound", :constraints => { :rest => /.*/ }
```

to redirect all "other" stuff to application#notfound. The problem is that plugins with own routes where set *below* shis rule and never gets called.

Comment: why not simply edit public/404.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely not the only person having this problem. I know it's frustrating, but give it some time - I'm confident the Rails team will put together something simple and elegant. I'm in a similar position, only I need to know the incorrect url resource the user entered.

A quick Google search and I found this article demonstrating a [full solution to the Rails 3.0 rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError problem](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution). The solution involves Route Globbing and solves my need to both handle incorrect urls and capture the url entered. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

Make a catch-all route and put it as the last rule in your routes.rb file.

```
match "*rest" => "application#notfound"
```

you also get whatever the path was as a parameter thru `params[:rest]` in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Put this rule last.. Routing matches from top to bottom so if it did find a match then it stops there.

Comment: I put it as tha last rule. The problem is, that *plugins* will be added _after_ the application rules, so I had to find another way :(

Comment: I see where the issue is. Plugins should be providing a way for you to call their routes. For example devise provides devise_for routing methods.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not the best approach, but it will works while you don't find better solution

for rails 2.3, at the application controller, catch the exception like

```
rescue_from(ActionController::RoutingError) { redirect_to "/xpto" #add your code here }
```

Rails 3

At initializer put a code like:

```
module ActionDispatch
  class ShowExceptions
   def render_exception(env, exception)
     if exception.kind_of? ActionController::RoutingError
       render(500, 'it was routing error')
     else
       render(500, "some other error")
     end
   end
 end
```

end

or something more clean like:

- https://gist.github.com/522944
- https://gist.github.com/522924

or:

```
match '/:anything', :to => "home#routing_error", :constraints => { :anything => /.*/ }
```

but maybe this last match won't be good for you as it'll override all routes from plugins/engines. I  think that best solution is to use custom rack middleware for handling special cases.